# 500 error with Nginx and WordPress pretty permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, permalinks

Ran into a 500 issue when running Nginx and WP together and setting pretty permalinks. I've been trying a bunch of different methods from Google but none seems to help.

Config -

```
server {
        listen   80;

        root /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name .mydomain.com;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }
}
```

All files load perfectly well, and the pages work if using the default permalinks setting. Strange thing is, if I check the network log I first see a 200 OK being received, then immediately followed by a 500. Any ideas?

Edit: Setting to close as I'm switching to Apache instead. Will mark correct answer as it seems to have helped others.

Comment: Can you include the relevant part of your error log?

Comment: and you should first include fastcgi_params and then change it.. (or you will overwrite your own modifications in the location part.)

Comment: Error log is empty. And I changed and moved fastcgi_params to be the first line under location (was this what you meant?). Still same results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

AND:

```
fastcgi_index /index.php;
```

(note the / )

Comment: `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` in your location block may help to.
i use a slighty modified version of https://github.com/perusio/wordpress-nginx for my setup, this works rather well.

Comment: Tried it, didn't make any difference I'm afraid. Will check out that url though and see if I can find a way.

Answer (score 4):

Also above answer by Rufinus is correct.

Here is correct . You Forget to define Index . So nginx don't know which file to lockup and process. Hope this help u out.

```
location / {
index index.php index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

**Your Config does not have fastcgi_parm** .

add this line to your config.  Its main part of Nginx Config.

change **/home/public_html** with your website path location

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Here is my Whole wordpress config file. I Hope that works. **Its working Nginx config file with pretty urls.**

```
server {
                listen 80;
                server_name example.com;
                root /home/public_html;
                index index.php index.htm index.html;

location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

location / {
index index.php index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
location /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|xml)$ {
    access_log        off;
    log_not_found     off;
    expires           360d;
}


location ~ /\. {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off; 
    deny all;
}


location ~ .php$ {
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}
 }
```

Comment: I'm using it on nginx 1.6 and its working. did u clear browser cache? Sometimes browser keep cache. try using private window.

Comment: did u try it @StaffanEstberg

Comment: I just tried it Rajlaksh and sorry but it doesn't work, still getting a 500. I think I'm giving up on Nginx for now and will switch to Apache. A lot less headache...

Comment: @StaffanEstberg this will reload nginx config so modified change can apply.

Comment: No, none of theses suggestions worked for me. I gave up on Nginx simply.

Comment: i give full config. Its working on all nginx. copy this config and paste it in your config. if its not provide me TV :)

Comment: @StaffanEstberg my config has full code. U accepted answer has that in my full config too.